# Why isn't Java able to infer the type correctly in this code?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Code for demo purposes only.

This does not compile:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   final List<Optional<Dog>> dogs = Arrays.stream(new String[]{"a", "b"})
       .map((code) -> {
         try {
           return Optional.of(new Dog());
         } catch (RuntimeException e) {
           return Optional.empty();
         }
       })
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }

class Dog{}
```

This does compile:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   final List<Optional<Dog>> dogs = Arrays.stream(new String[]{"a", "b"})
       .map((code) -> getDog(code))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }

 private static Optional<Dog> getDog(String code) {
   try {
     return Optional.of(new Dog());
   } catch (RuntimeException e) {
     return Optional.empty();
   }
 }

class Dog{}
```

Is there any other way to tell Java that the type of `Optional.empty()` in the first example is of type `Optional<Dog>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any other way to tell Java that the type of `Optional.empty()` in the first example is of type `Optional<Dog>`?

```
Optional.<Dog>empty()
```

When you call a static method with template parameters, you use the above syntax to explicitly specify the parameters.

It is shown on the [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) page:

> ```
> public class Util {
>     public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
>         return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
>                p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The complete syntax for invoking this method would be:
>
> ```
> Pair<Integer, String> p1 = new Pair<>(1, "apple");
> Pair<Integer, String> p2 = new Pair<>(2, "pear");
> boolean same = Util.<Integer, String>compare(p1, p2);
> ```

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether the method is `static`. E.g. you can also solve the problem by specifying explicit types to the instance method `Stream.map`: `… .<Optional<Dog>>map(code -> { … })`.